# Downloading IText .pdf using JS/AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, download, itext

I have a page that creates an Itext pdf document and then the document gets downloaded. The following code will do just that. But the page refreshes. I would like for the page to not have to refresh. I think that would provide a better user experience such that the page form inputs wouldn't get wiped out on the page refresh.

Is there a better way to handle this task such that the page does not have to be refreshed? Is there some modification to this existing code that can be done to avoid a page refresh?

labelReprint.js:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "labelReprint.aspx/DoLabelPrint",
        data: "{'type':'" + lblType + "','scan':'" + scan + "','qty':'" + qty + "','split':'" + split + "'}",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (result) {
            console.log('Downloading .pdf');

            //pdf
            var downloadpdf = $('<a id="downloadpdf" download="' + fileName + '.pdf" href="data:application/pdf;base64,' + result.d + '" >');
            $('#download').append(downloadpdf);
            document.getElementById("downloadpdf").click();
            $("#downloadpdf").remove();

        },
        error: function (result) {
            console.log(result.responseJSON.Message + "\n\r\n\r" + result.responseJSON.StackTrace);
        }
    });
```

The follow function gets called from labelReprint.aspx/DoLabelPrint referenced in the AJAX above. This handles the Itext/pdf creation.

```
Public Shared Function mfgrLabel(ByVal barCode As String, ByVal user As String) As String
    Dim MS As System.IO.MemoryStream = New System.IO.MemoryStream()

    Dim subs = New subs

    Dim pSize As New iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(252, 36)
    Dim pdfDoc As New iTextSharp.text.Document(pSize, 0.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F)

    Dim writer As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, MS)

    pdfDoc.Open()

    Dim cb As PdfContentByte = writer.DirectContent

    Dim tblLbl As iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPTable = New iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPTable(2)

    Dim bf As BaseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA_BOLD, BaseFont.WINANSI, False)
    Dim tRsmall As iTextSharp.text.Font = iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 5, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL)
    Dim tR As iTextSharp.text.Font = iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 6, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL)
    Dim tRMed As iTextSharp.text.Font = iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 7, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL)
    Dim tRMedLrg As iTextSharp.text.Font = iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL)
    Dim tRLrg As iTextSharp.text.Font = iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL)
    Dim tXRLrg As iTextSharp.text.Font = iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL)

    Dim cBlankNB As iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPCell = New iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPCell

    cBlankNB.Border = 0

    tblLbl.HorizontalAlignment = 0

    '***************  Labels ***************************
    Dim cellTimestamp As iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPCell = New iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPCell(New iTextSharp.text.Phrase(barCode, tR)) '"Inovar P/N:"
    Dim cPartNo As iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPCell = New iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPCell(New iTextSharp.text.Phrase(barCode.Split("|")(0) & " " & barCode.Split("|")(1), tRMedLrg))

    Dim uInfo As String = user.ToUpper & " " & Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy").ToUpper

    Dim pInfo As String = barCode.Split("|")(0) & " " & barCode.Split("|")(1)

    cellTimestamp.Border = 0

    cPartNo.Border = 0
    '**************************************************

    '************  Bar Codes **************************

    Dim safeFileName As String = subs.fixFileNameBeforeSave(barCode.Split("|")(1))
    Dim inoDm As Barcodes.DataMatrix.DataMatrixWebControl = New Barcodes.DataMatrix.DataMatrixWebControl
    inoDm.DataToEncode = barCode.Split("|")(1)
    If File.Exists(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(safeFileName & ".jpg")) Then
        File.Delete(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(safeFileName & ".jpg"))
    End If

    inoDm.SaveToImageFile(25, 25, HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(safeFileName & ".jpg"), 300, Barcodes.DataMatrix.Dimensions.dmMM)

    Dim inoDmImg As iTextSharp.text.Image
    inoDmImg = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(safeFileName & ".jpg"))

    inoDmImg.ScaleAbsolute(25, 25)

    Dim inoPBC As iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPCell
    inoPBC = New iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPCell(iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(inoDmImg))

    inoPBC.VerticalAlignment = 6
    inoPBC.HorizontalAlignment = 0
    inoPBC.Border = 0
    inoPBC.PaddingLeft = 10.0F
    inoPBC.PaddingTop = 15.0F
    '************  End Bar Codes **************************


    inoPBC.PaddingTop = 5.0F
    cPartNo.NoWrap = True
    inoPBC.Colspan = 2

    tblLbl.AddCell(inoPBC)

    pdfDoc.Add(tblLbl)

    cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 8)
    cb.BeginText()
    cb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT, pInfo, 40, 20, 0) '180
    cb.EndText()

    cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 4)
    cb.BeginText()
    cb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT, uInfo, 40, 4, 0) '180
    cb.EndText()

    pdfDoc.Close()

    'Clean up
    If File.Exists(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(safeFileName & ".jpg")) Then
        File.Delete(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(safeFileName & ".jpg"))
    End If

    Return System.Convert.ToBase64String(MS.ToArray())
```

Any thoughts or insights would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In the done of Ajax, put the following code:

```
var binaryString = window.atob(result);
var binaryLen = binaryString.length;
var bytes = new Uint8Array(binaryLen);
for (var idx = 0; idx < binaryLen; idx++) {
            var ascii = binaryString.charCodeAt(idx);
            bytes[idx] = ascii;
}
var blob = new Blob([bytes]);
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
var fileName = "filename.pdf";
link.download = fileName;
link.click();
```